# Unlinking a work laptop from my personal Apple devices

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, ipad, icloud

I own an iPad and an iPhone. I also have a work MacBook Air laptop which I will be returning to the owners soon. How do I stop this device linking to my personal iPad and iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to follow these steps on the MacBook Air:

1. Backup any data you may want to keep (including data on iCloud)
2. Open iTunes
3. From the menu bar go to Account > Authorizations > Deauthorize This Computer
4. Enter your Apple ID and password
5. Click Deauthorise
6. Now also go to Apple > System Preferences
7. Click on the iCloud preference pane
8. If it's selected, then deselect the Find My Mac checkbox
9. Now totally sign out of iCloud
10. Exit System Preferences
11. Launch the Messages app
12. Go to Messages > Preferences > Accounts
13. Select the Accounts tab
14. Sign out of any personal accounts
15. Follow [these steps](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204904) to reinstall macOS

Now you're MacBook Air is ready to hand back.

**OPTIONAL:** If you can't do Step 15 (e.g. you're not allowed to, etc) then you could also do the following (assuming you're allowed to):

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups
2. Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign to add a new account. When you do, ensure that it is an Administrator account.
3. Exit System Preferences
4. Restart the Mac and login to the new user account you just created
5. Once you're logged in, go to System Preferences > Users & Groups
6. Click on the <kbd>-</kbd> button to delete your original account. Select the appropriate option and click on <kbd>Delete User</kbd>.

Now your MacBook Air is ready to hand back.